How to use Waveshare RS485 CAN HAT with Raspberry OS "bookworm" to read energy meter?
With my Waveshare RS485 CAN HAT ("Raspberry Pi small size and low cost RS485 CAN"), attached to Pi 3 Model B+ 1.3, Raspberry OS "bookworm", I followed the manufacturer's instructions to use Modbus over RS485 but failed to set up the device.
I am unsure at which point the setup fails. My intention was to communicate via Modbus-RTU with my Eastron SDM120M / SDM72D-M energy meters. Communication with Modbus-TCP with a RS485 to Eth works as expected and using a scope, I can see the traffic at the Modbus. The energy meters are apparently ok. No traffic when using Raspi & HAT.
Can anybody provide some up-to-date sample code which uses today's libraries/packages for Modbus-RTU communication?
What did I do?
1. Physical Connection
Modbus A+ and B- of Raspi HAT and Eastron are connected, GND is left open (HAT has no GND connector).
2. Serial Port Activation
With raspi-config, I disabled "login shell accessible over serial" and enabled "serial port hadware". My /boot/firmware/config.txt contains
enable_uart=1
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt

I was expecting to see a positive message at bootup and got:
[    2.877650] uart-pl011 3f201000.serial: there is not valid maps for state default
[    2.877888] uart-pl011 3f201000.serial: cts_event_workaround enabled
[    2.878302] 3f201000.serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x3f201000 (irq = 99, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2

which I considered positive. My /dev/serial0 is a softlink to ttyAMA0 which is a character special 204/64.
3. Python Modbus Package
I installed the minimalmodbus Python package in a Python virtual environment.
4. Read Energy Meter, 1st attempt
However, when trying to run a minimal script
#!/opt/modbus-venv/bin/python3
# coding=utf-8

import minimalmodbus

ea = minimalmodbus.Instrument("/dev/ttyAMA0", 1)
ea.serial.baudrate = 9600
ea.serial.timeout = 0.5 # seconds
ea.debug = True
print (ea)

FREQ = round(ea.read_float(70,4),2)
print('Freq = {:-6} Hz'.format(FREQ))

I get the error message:
(modbus-venv) root@modbus:/opt/Eastron# ./read.py 
minimalmodbus.Instrument<id=0x7f8a642310, address=1, mode=rtu, close_port_after_each_call=False, precalculate_read_size=True, clear_buffers_before_each_transaction=True, handle_local_echo=False, debug=True, serial=Serial<id=0x7f8a594d30, open=True>(port='/dev/ttyAMA0', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=0.5, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)>
MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 9 bytes back): 01 04 00 46 00 02 90 1E (8 bytes)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port /dev/ttyAMA0
MinimalModbus debug mode. No sleep required before write. Time since previous read: 2008426.06 ms, minimum silent period: 4.01 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument:  (0 bytes), roundtrip time: 0.5 ms. Timeout for reading: 500.0 ms.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/Eastron/./read.py", line 13, in <module>
    FREQ = round(ea.read_float(70,4),2)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/modbus-venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/minimalmodbus.py", line 742, in read_float
    self._generic_command(
  File "/opt/modbus-venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/minimalmodbus.py", line 1276, in _generic_command
    payload_from_slave = self._perform_command(functioncode, payload_to_slave)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/modbus-venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/minimalmodbus.py", line 1353, in _perform_command
    response_bytes = self._communicate(request_bytes, number_of_bytes_to_read)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/modbus-venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/minimalmodbus.py", line 1521, in _communicate
    raise NoResponseError("No communication with the instrument (no answer)")
minimalmodbus.NoResponseError: No communication with the instrument (no answer)

5. Read Energy Meter, 2nd attempt
Trying mbpoll -v -m rtu -a 3 -t3:hex -r 0 -c 2 -0 -1 -b 9600 -P none /dev/serial0 (device has indeed mb address 3) yields:
debug enabled
Set mode=rtu
iGetIntList(3)
Integer found: 3
iCount=1
Set function=3
Set format=hex
Set start reference=0
Set number of values=2
Set rtu baudrate=9600
Set rtu parity=none
Set device=/dev/serial0
mbpoll 1.0-0 - FieldTalk(tm) Modbus(R) Master Simulator
Copyright © 2015-2019 Pascal JEAN, https://github.com/epsilonrt/mbpoll
This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; type 'mbpoll -w' for details.

Opening /dev/serial0 at 9600 bauds (N, 8, 1)
Set response timeout to 1 sec, 0 us
Protocol configuration: Modbus RTU
Slave configuration...: address = [3]
                        start reference = 0, count = 2
Communication.........: /dev/serial0,       9600-8N1 
                        t/o 1.00 s, poll rate 1000 ms
Data type.............: 16-bit register, input register table

-- Polling slave 3...
[03][04][00][00][00][02][70][29]
Waiting for a confirmation...
ERROR Connection timed out: select
Read input register failed: Connection timed out

What's wrong?

"What's wrong?" You have failed to explain what Pi, what OS, what YOU have done and what is connected.
